# download php file from shell script

Tags: php

I have one complex scenario. Here is the scenario.

I have one shell script which checking license from shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
macid="00:e0:4c:36:20:43"

/usr/bin/curl -o /tmp/.chk -d "mac_id=$macid" http://www.example.com/licensecheck.php
```

In example.com/licensecheckfile.php contain code to license check

here is my licensecheck.php file is

```
<?php
// here is code to check macid in database and return status whether it is **expired**,**running**, or **not register**

include './download.php';
?>
```

and download.php file is

```
<?php   
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('file.sh'));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.sh'));
    readfile('http://example/test.txt');
    exit;
?>
```

So this can download file as file.sh but as I told that file is calling from shell script it is show output as below output in /tmp/.chk

```
registered#!/bin/bash
echo "### STARTED AT | `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`"
```

But I need file.sh as new file and /tmp/.chk should contain registered and file.sh should contain

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "### STARTED AT | `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`"
```

Comment: Well... somewhere in the process you're doing `echo 'registered';`...!? Simply, err, *don't*!?

Comment: I want two different file, file.sh should contain shell script and /tmp/.chk should contain result of license check.